# Is 'Noh' different from 'noh' in Vim

Tags: vim

I know that

```
:noh
```

is for "no highlight" - to remove highlighting in text.

Sometimes by mistake I type

```
:Noh
```

and it replaces something which I do not know and I have to do `control-Z`.

What does `:Noh` do in Vim?

Edit: With command `:h Noh`, I get help for `noh` only.

Comment: Have you tried `:h Noh`?

Comment: I have added my response to your comment in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this:

```
:Noh
E492: Not an editor command: :Noh
```

Built-in commands (except [`:X`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3AX)) start with a *lowercase* letter; user-defined commands (via [`:command`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand)) **must** start with an *uppercase* letter. (The `:help` has a case-insensitive search fallback, that's why you've found the original built-in command.)

So, you have a custom `:Noh` command (or something that starts with these letters and is unique). What that is and where it was defined can be found out via

```
:verbose command Noh
```

If you wanted to know that it does (the "replaces something"), you could `:debug Noh`, or `:20verbose Noh`.

Comment: `:verbose command Noh` prints out: `Nohash      0    %                             <line1>,<line2>s/^# //g | noh  ` . (I had created this command to remove `#` added earlier to comment out lines of python code). So this command `Nohash` is getting executed when I run `Noh` .

Comment: Correct. You could rename that command to avoid it being accidentally triggered. Or define a `:command! -bar Nohlsearch nohlsearch`, which would force you to type out the full (or at least longer so that it's unique) name.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.